# ANTLR Tree rewriting based on pattern

Tags: antlr, antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree

I've got a fairly basic grammar in ANTLR 3 and I am looking to do the following:
 - If a '+' appears in front of a 'term', just remove it as it is redundant (done).
 - If a '-' appears in front of a 'term', keep it, however add a '0' to the first child node so that I effectively go from "-2" to "0-2".

```
expression:
  unaryterm ((ADD^ | MINUS^) term)*
;

unaryterm:
  (ADD! | MINUS^)? term
;
```

I've had a go at tree rewriting but seem to get stuck when it comes to matching the possible '-'.

Note: ADD represents '+' and MINUS represents '-'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `INTEGER` is your desired token type for the literal `0`, you could use the following:

```
unaryterm
    :   ADD! term
    |   MINUS term -> ^(MINUS INTEGER["0"] term)
    |   term
    ;
```